# Link against shared lib which is using another shared lib without rpath

Tags: unix, gcc, dynamic-linking

Let's say I have a library lib1.so created like that:

```
gcc 1.cpp -o lib1.so  -shared
```

And I have another library lib2.so created in this way:

```
gcc 2.cpp -o lib2.so -shared -L. -l1
```

But linking against lib2.so

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -L. -l2
```

gives a warning:

```
warning: lib1.so, needed by lib2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

But AFAIK the use of rpath is discouraged because then the library can not be moved to another location.

How do I link "main" against "lib2.so" without specifying "lib1.so" and rpath?

Answer (score 0):

The RPATH header in the binary takes precedence so even if the library has no RPATH header, it will still be found **IF** you have copied it to the directory mentioned in `-rpath`